# Is the shadow of the earth coming up almost matching in size with the moon a coincidence?

Tags: geometry, classical-mechanics

The fool that I am, today was the first time I wondered how come the shadow of the earth is almost same in size as the moon. I mean, as I was looking at the crescent moon in the evening, it came upon me that the crescent was like this:

[image]

and not like this:

[image]

neither do we see as the moon like this:

[image]

Of course, this must be because the sizes of moon and earth along with the distance between them. However my question is if this is a mere coincidence, one of the many things that makes planet earth unique or is there a deeper relation between the sizes, masses, distance ? Is there any mathematical equation involving the gravitational constant that describes this fact ?

Comment: As Carlos explained the Moon's crescent is not about Earth's shadows. If you have a telescope take a look at Venus. When it is relatively close to Earth you will see a similar crescent. This is due to Venus being closer to the Sun than we are, and the crescent shows because only a small part of Venus' surface visible to us is sunlit. For example Mars never shows a thin crescent, because we are always mostly between Mars and Sun. OTOH, when viewed from the Earth, the Moon and the Sun do cover nearly the same angle. This is a coincidence. But it gives us awesome solar eclipses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you see a crescent moon, the dark part of the Moon is not the shadow of the earth: it is the “the dark side of the Moon”, i.e. the side of the Moon that is not currently lightened by the Sun.

[image: Crescent moon]

The inner curve of what you are actually looking is not a circle but an ellipse.

The shadow of Earth in the Moon is what you see in a Lunar eclipse, and it does not match the size of the Moon.